# Unable to read HDFS file with Go lang

Tags: go, hadoop, hdfs

While trying to read a simple file with colinmarc go module by creating a executable file in go , it not able to read the file.

The below location is a HDFS location. It is able to connect to namenode.

```
$ ./hdfsReader "namenode:port" "/usr/username/test/a.txt"
panic: open /usr/username/test/a.txt: unexpected EOF
```